# Check if there any other users online

Tags: chat, twilio

We are building a customer support chat application using Twilio's programmable chat sdk. We classify the chat users into visitors and agents where visitors users looking for support and agents are support guys replying to visitor's queries.

We have a requirement where we want the chat feature to be available to a visitor only if at least one agent is online. If none are online, then the visitor will not be able to start a new chat but instead get an agent unavailable message.

How can one achieve this using Twilio's sdk? 
We enabled reachability on the service instance.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This might be a good time to consider [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter). TaskRouter is a set of resources and APIs that model workers, availability and tasks throughout a workflow. In TaskRouter you would set up your agents as [Workers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workers) and give them [Activities](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/activities) that define whether they are online and available or not available at all.

You could then [set up a workflow](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workflow-configuration) that directs incoming messages from users to available workers and if there are no available workers, return your unavailable message.

Take a look and see what you think.

Comment: Is TaskRouter supported for Programmable Chat as well?

Comment: You can use TaskRouter with anything really, you just have to manage creating the Tasks themselves (whereas with Programmable Voice you can have a voice call create tasks just by using `<Enqueue>`.